# How to use SyntaxNet parser/tagger with spaCy API?

Tags: python, nlp, syntaxnet, spacy

I have been using [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) Python package to parse and tag text and using the resulting dependency tree and other attributes to derive meaning. Now I would like to use SyntaxNet's Parsey McParseface for parsing and dependency tagging (which seems better), but I would like to keep using spaCy API because it is so easy to use and it does many things that Parsey doesn't. SyntaxNet outputs POS tags and dependency tags/tree in a CoNLL-format:

1. Bob    _    NOUN    NNP    _    2    nsubj    _    _
2. brought    _    VERB    VBD    _    0    ROOT    _    _
3. the    _    DET    DT    _    4    det    _    _
4. pizza    _    NOUN    NN    _    2    dobj    _    _
5. to    _    ADP    IN    _    2    prep    _    _
6. Alice    _    NOUN    NNP    _    5    pobj    _    _
7. .    _    .    .    _    2    punct    _    _

and spaCy seems to be able to read CoNLL format right [here](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/blob/master/bin/parser/conll_parse.py). But I can't figure out where in spaCy's API does it take a CoNLL-fromatted string.

Answer (score 3):

From [the spaCy blog](https://spacy.io/blog/syntaxnet-in-context):

> Obviously, we want to build a bridge between Parsey McParseface and spaCy, so that you can use the more accurate model with the sweeter spaCy API.

However, it looks like there still plenty of work to be done before this is possible.

See also the spaCy author's response [here](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/issues/432).

Answer (score 1):

Has anybody managed to get SyntaxNet running as a service yet? There's no problem loading annotations into spaCy. The problem is that SyntaxNet is primarily a research system, and it was sufficient for the experimental needs to operate on batches of text, from disk.

If you're content to read from disk, then there should be no problem --- just read in the CoNLL format, and then you can apply the annotations to spaCy Doc objects.

Comment: I'm also looking into that, SyntaxNet as a service, I still haven't looked at this in detail, but this seems to be something in the direction:

https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/

Answer (score 1):

I did not tried with spaCy, but I've managed to use SyntaxNet's output inside Python NLTK's classes/structures, like DependencyGraph and Tree.

Here is a full example:

http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/03/25/syntaxnet/